# How to restrict firebase web apikey on google cloud console without breaking facebook login?

Tags: firebase, facebook-login, google-cloud-console

I'm trying to restrict with http referrers my firebase web api key with the domains of our production and test environments.
By accessing to the google cloud console, selecting `APIs & Services` -> `Credentials`, I'm successfully able to restrict the API key usage with the given http referrers and everything seems to work just fine, except for the facebook login feature that returns an error.

Is there a domain that makes use of the apikey once attempting facebook login that I should whitelist as well? If so, which one?

Comment: DId you manage to solve this issue ?

Comment: nope :( firebase just creates them like that apparently